# How to understand this Observable Timeout Sample Code?

Tags: reactjs, observable

I am beginner of ReactX JS. Below is an sample code related with timeout given in site http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timeout.html. I cannot understand the explanation given in site. Does somebody can explain in simple words and logic.

The major concerns are:

1. why `outputs` are `0, 1, 2`, but not `200, 300, 350`?
2. Does `0, 1, 2` correspond to `200, 300 ,350` respectively?
3. What is the meaning of `Rx.Observale`? Where the `Rx` come from?
4. `map` operator return `i`, does `i` equal `0, 1, 2`?
5. What does `Rx.Observale.for().map().timeoutWithSelector()` want
       to do?

Sample Code

```
var array = [
    200,
    300,
    350,
    400
];

var source = Rx.Observable
    .for(array, function (x) {
        return Rx.Observable.timer(x);
    })
    .map(function (x, i) { return i; })
    .timeoutWithSelector(function (x) {
        return Rx.Observable.timer(400);
    });

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) { console.log('Next: ' + x); },
    function (err) { console.log('Error: ' + err); },
    function () { console.log('Completed'); });
```

Output:

```
Next: 0
Next: 1
Next: 2
Error: Error: Timeout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rx](http://reactivex.io/) is a library. An [Observable](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) is used like a Promise since they are both used for asynchronous tasks/requests.

To explain the code:

The source variable is an Observable. The source observable is subscribed to at the var subscription line, the Observable is not triggered/called until it is subscribed to since it is [lazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading). Subscribe takes three functions as parameters the first for success, second error, last complete.

Once source is subscribed to it begins with the for which loops over the given array. The given function is invoked with each element in the array. So in this case for each element in array an Observable is returned and the timer means that given time (now + x) the Observable will send a number starting at 0 and incrementing every time. So for the first element 200 the Observable will wait 200 and then return 0. For the next element 300 the Observable will wait 300 and then return 1. This continues for the entire array.

The map function, the value returned is x and i is an incrementer. So it would first be 0, 0 then 1, 1 and continue for the array.

The timeoutWithSelector means that if the Observable does not complete before the given function then an error will be thrown.

So it outputs 0, 1, 2, Error because ONLY the first 3 elements in the array complete before 400. 0 finishes at 200, 1 finishes 100 later (300-200) and then 2 finishes 50 later (350-100-200). At 400 the error is thrown and the Observable stops. So it never comes to completion, so "Completed" is never printed.

Hopefully, this helps.